# How do check if a file is an image or a ascii text file?

Tags: elixir

How do check if a file is an image or a ascii text file?
For example to check "file1" is ascii text or binary image/png file.

Comment: I'd say that you should use general, language-agnostic approach. Scan the header/contents, and guess.

Comment: When you say 'image' do you mean check if it's binary content or text?

Comment: What about files that are [both an image and ASCII text](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/pgm.html)?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not familiar with Elixir, but the obvious language-agnostic solution is to use the [`file`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_(command)) command-line tool (which is standard on Unix-like systems, including Linux and MacOS, and can be installed as a third-party application on Windows) or the *libmagic* library that it's based on.  These methods should work on any language that can invoke external programs and/or call a dynamically linked library with a C-style ABI (possibly via a wrapper module of some kind).

The way `file` and *libmagic* work is by reading a precompiled [list of simple characteristic patterns](http://netbsd.gw.com/cgi-bin/man-cgi?magic+5+NetBSD-current) for different file formats and testing each of them against the contents of the file.  If you wanted, you *could* write a parser for the pattern format yourself, and thus produce a pure Elixir reimplementation of `file`.  I'm not saying that this would be trivial, but the advantage (over just hard-coding a bunch of file format tests yourself) is that you could still use the same pattern database, which already contains patters for a *huge* number of formats, and is being constantly updated.

In any case, if you're *only* interested in distinguishing a few different types of files (say, PNG images and plain ASCII text files), then hardcoding the relevant tests yourself may be feasible.  For example:

- PNG image files have [a fixed 8-byte header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#File_header), whose presence at the beginning of the file is a pretty good indication that this is a PNG image.  If you want to be extra sure, you could read the following `IHDR` chunk and verify that its type and CRC checksum are correct.  Other image formats (like JPEG and GIF) have similar [format signatures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_signature) of their own.
- A pure [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) text file should consist only of bytes in the printable ASCII range (32-126) plus a few control characters (most commonly TAB = 9, LF = 10 and CR = 13).  Text files using other ASCII-compatible character sets (such as UTF-8) may also contain bytes in the range 128-255; [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), in particular, is easy to identify by the fact that bytes in that range will always occur in groups of two or more, and in a [very specific pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description).